# Connect PHP application to spark sql thrift server

Tags: php, thrift, apache-spark-sql

How to connect a PHP application to spark sql thrift server?

We have a hadoop cluster and running on top of it spark sql thrift server. From our java applications we can use hive JDBC driver to connect to the server and execute queries.

But, we have other applications developed in PHP which needs to connect to the spark sql thrift server.

We followed [this link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient#HiveClient-PHP) but when we try to open the script in browser, the spark sql thrift server throws this exception.

```
15/03/05 11:53:19 ERROR TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:182)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
    ... 4 more
```

I can not figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you could add the following it would shed some more light...
Add your thrift server configuration.
Add hive-site.xml.
Add thrift server logs.

My guess is that you have SASL enabled while the PHP doesn't support it.
If so - you could add to hive-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>  
    <value>NOSASL</value>
</property>
```